# Database update based on two input files

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using a form with multiple input text and two input files to update a database table.

I set up two inputs hidden with the image name as value.

If an image is set just for `imageFile`, i need to update just that data, same for `imageFileBanner`.

If both are set, i need to update all fields.

How can i update just one image?

```
    if(!empty($_FILES['imageFile']['name']) && empty($_POST['imageIsSet']) !empty($_FILES['imageFileBanner']['name'])){
        $sql = $database->update(sprintf("UPDATE taburi SET nume='%s', logo='%s', vizibil='%d', ordine='%d', banner='%s' WHERE id='%d'", $nume, $img, $status, $ordine, $img_banner, $id));

    }else{
        $sql = $database->update(sprintf("UPDATE taburi SET nume='%s', vizibil='%d', ordine='%d' WHERE id='%d'", $nume, $status, $ordine, $id));

    }
```

With this statement if i select a file for `ImageFile` , it will set my `imageFileBanner` as empty on update and vice versa.

And here is my form

```
      <form id="editTabForm" name="editTabForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="info"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> Completati numele tab-ului apoi selectati o imagine pentru afisare.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="control-group form-group">
              <label for="tab-name">Nume tab</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tab-name" id="tab-name" placeholder="nume tab" value="{$tab.nume}" />
            </div>
            <div class="control-group form-group">
              <label>Status</label>
              <select name="status" class="category-tree">
                {if $tab.vizibil == 1}
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Activ</option>
                <option value="0">Inactiv</option>
                {else}
                <option value="1">Activ</option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Inactiv</option>
                {/if}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group form-group">
              <label for="tab-order">Ordinea afisarii in meniul orizontal</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tab-order" id="tab-order" style="width:20%;" value="{$tab.ordine}"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="control-group form-group">
              <label for="image">Selectati o imagine pentru afisarea tab-ului</label>
              <div id="imagePreview">
                {if $tab.logo}
                <img src="{$website}/media/taburi/{$tab.logo}" class="imagePreview thumbnail" style="max-width:50px; max-height:50px;" />
                {else}
                <img src="/admin/mmadmin/template/assets/img-upload-50_50.png" class="imagePreview thumbnail" style="max-width:50px; max-height:50px;" />
                {/if}
              </div>
              <input type="file" name="imageFile" id="image" />
            </div>
            <div class="control-group form-group">
              <label for="image">Selectati o imagine default pentru tab</label>
              <div id="imagePreviewBanner">
                {if $tab.banner}
                <img src="{$website}/media/cat/{$tab.banner}" class="imagePreviewBanner thumbnail" style="max-width:150px; max-height:150px;" />
                {else}
                <img src="/admin/mmadmin/template/assets/img-upload-150_150.png" class="imagePreviewBanner thumbnail" style="max-width:150px; max-height:150px;" />
                {/if}
              </div>
              <input type="file" name="imageFileBanner" id="imageBanner" />
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$tab.id}" />
              <input type="hidden" name="imageIsSet" value="{$tab.logo}" />
              <input type="hidden" name="bannerIsSet" value="{$tab.banner}" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Anuleaza</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="update-tab" data-id="{$tab.id}">Salveaza</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

[image]

Comment: show us your HTML form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved::
Is there any better way ?

```
if(!empty($_FILES['imageFile']['name'])){

            $sql = $database->update(sprintf("UPDATE taburi SET nume='%s', logo='%s', vizibil='%d', ordine='%d' WHERE id='%d'", $nume, $img, $status, $ordine, $id));

        }else if(!empty($_FILES['imageFileBanner']['name'])){

            $sql = $database->update(sprintf("UPDATE taburi SET nume='%s', vizibil='%d', ordine='%d', banner='%s' WHERE id='%d'", $nume, $status, $ordine, $img_banner, $id));

        }else if(!empty($_FILES['imageFile']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['imageFileBanner']['name'])){

            $sql = $database->update(sprintf("UPDATE taburi SET nume='%s', logo='%s', vizibil='%d', banner='%s', ordine='%d' WHERE id='%d'", $nume, $img, $status, $ordine, $img_banner, $id));

        }else{

            $sql = $database->update(sprintf("UPDATE taburi SET nume='%s', vizibil='%d', ordine='%d' WHERE id='%d'", $nume, $status, $ordine, $id));

        }
```